# Why is my location in cyrillics?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Over at my careers profile, my location - Riga, Latvia is in Russian for some reason.

> [image]

Is this a bug or do I have Russian set as my location/language in settings somewhere?

Comment: The link you posted is viewable only by SE employees, for everyone else it's an error page. Please share link to your public Careers profile, if you have any.

Comment: Anyway, this field is editable - what you see when you try to edit it?

Comment: Smells like a localization issue. Was this a very recent change, or maybe the launch of SO.ru is partially to blame (which launched a couple of weeks ago)?

Comment: @psubsee2003 More like 6-8 weeks ago... ru.SO launched at the end of March.

Comment: The Careers website is using Google Maps API when editing the location, so this is most likely [tag:status-bydesign] each user can enter his/her location in the native language and not just English.

Comment: I was about to write how the text does not change no matter what I enter in Location field, but it seems that saving the google suggestion a couple of times finally fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This was a problem with how Careers retrieved and used geocoding results from the browser. For English (US), we were mistakenly using the browser language when querying the Google geocoding API rather than English. This, in turn, led us to cache and re-use these query results as English results when, in fact, they were not.

Careers has been updated to use the English version of the geocoding API rather than the browser language version when viewing the English (US) version of the site. In addition, cached results that were obviously in the wrong language have been purged. **We did not, however, attempt to correct existing data such as profile locations.** If you see a location that should be in English but is not, re-enter it and save again. This should correct the problem.

If you see this problem again or do not wish to attempt to correct it yourself, please don't hesitate to create a new Meta post and someone from the Careers team will check into it. Thanks for your patience.