# Careers: some relocation country names are in another language

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I added a bunch of "willing to relocate to" locations to my CV, and the country names have auto-corrected to a variety of languages:

> Active candidate interested in **full-time position**. Willing to relocate to **Montreal, QC, Canada; Vancouver, BC, Kanada; Stockholm, Sweden; Berlin, Germany; Munich, Germany; Bergen, Norsko; London, UK; Copenhagen, Denmark**.

"Bergen, Norsko" should be "Bergen, Norway," and obviously "Vancouver, BC, Kanada" should be in "Canada." I think it's weird that Canada is in English in one instance and another language (possibly Swedish) in another. I'm not able to correct these locations to use English endo/exonyms, once I unfocus the location field it reverts back to the wrong value.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the report. This has been corrected; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266489/292696 for more information.

If you see this problem again or do not wish to attempt to correct it yourself by re-saving the location, please don't hesitate to create a new Meta post and someone from the Careers team will check into it. Thanks for your patience.